# Sum of Multiple VLOOKUPs

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to find a formula that would help me sum the results of multiple VLOOKUPs. For example, you have two sheets that look like the following:

**Sheet1**

Fruit______ Orange_Apple_Banana
Animal_____Horse__Wolf__Bear___Tiger

**Sheet2**

Orange_____ 3
Apple_______6
Tiger_______ 1
Banana_____ 7
Horse______ 10

So what I'm trying to do is sum the quantities of the different kinds of Fruits or Animals in Sheet2. Therefore, whenever I use this formula for a specific row in Sheet1, I would have the total number of fruits in Sheet2 (16) or the total number of animals (11).

Thanks in advance for the help!

P.S. Sorry if the example looks terrible! :(

Comment: Screen shots of the VLOOKUPS with annotations would probably help in this scenario. I think you can request an edit to this question by the moderators if you don't have enough rep for uploading a picture

Comment: Check out `sumifs`

Comment: @Raystafarian I looked at SUMIFS but I feel like that would require me to specify each and every condition. As the data changes and grows larger, it doesn't seem like a very good option. Maybe I am just understanding SUMIFS wrong, too. :(

Comment: @NathanTaylor I'll just go ahead and copy paste since I don't have a lot. 

=VLOOKUP(B2,Inventory!$A:$C,3,FALSE) --> Returns the QTY in column 3 of type B2 if it is found in the Inventory sheet.

This is what one of my VLOOKUPs look like right now. I'm only testing this for a static and small test sheet so I did another VLOOKUP for the next type =VLOOKUP(C2,Inventory!$A:$C,3,FALSE), and I have a SUM function adding those two. I would really like, if possible, to have one function that does all this that can change as the data is edited as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Rezylience wouldn't a simple =SUM() be sufficient? all you would need to do is reference the cells where the VLOOKUPS display the quantities of each fruit and of each animal separately.

Comment: @NathanTaylor That could be an option, but that means that I'd have to have separate cells that would hold the values of the VLOOKUPs. I'm trying to sort of save a step and combine everything into one formula, if there is anything like that available at all.

Comment: @Rezylience I'm guessing there would be a nestled IF statement possibility there but I'm unsure. plus this would be very difficult to accomplish. I'll do some testing

Comment: @NathanTaylor Thank you so much for your help. Do you know if this would be easier if I use VBA?

Comment: It is most certainly possible with VBA you can do background programming within macros, only my VBA knowledge is all but minimal so I don't think I can help you there

Comment: @NathanTaylor Perfect. I'll take a look at getting it done with VBA. A function would be friendlier, if there's any, for what I'm doing though. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Rezylience No problem sorry I couldn't highlight the real issue point blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula:

`=SUM(IF(B1:E1=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,""))`

Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

at the same time after writing the formula
B1:E1 is Orange Apple ... 
A2:A6 your Data in Sheet2 for Orange Apple Tiger ...
B2:B6 the corresponding number (quantity)
You can drag the formula for animals (that is why I used $ in formula)

[image]

[image]